# Route definition not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have 2 routes in my routes file.

```
Route::get('/deals/{merchant_name}?c={deal_id}', ['uses' => 'dealsvisibleController@index']);
Route::get('/deals/{merchant_name}', ['uses' =>'dealsController@index']);
```

Both routes are calling on a different controller function. The first route is however not working.

I am trying this in a 3rd controller.

```
 return redirect('deals/'.$merchant_name.'?c='.$deal_id);
```

However, when the page redirects, it is calling dealsController@index and not dealsvisibleController@index

Can someone help me with why this is happening.

Comment: why you had to use `?c={deal_id}` instead of `/{deal_id}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel's router considers only path when matching URLs to your routes. Therefore, if you redirect to **deals/someMerchant?c=someDealId** then it uses **deals/someMerchant** to match the URL.

You'll need to define the first route as **deals/{merchant_name}/{deal_id}** in order for this routing to work as you want it to.

Comment: Thanks. Changed the Route path as you suggested and got it working.